# child tables and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know there have been myriads of questions concerning primary and foreign keys. Looking through them, I cannot seem to find a simple answer to my question. My understanding of primary and foreign keys is that a foreign key is a column designated in a child table that refers back to a primary key as a column in a parent table. Is that correct, or do I have it backwards? If that is indeed correct, I am trying to find out why I am having difficulty creating a foreign key in a child table as such:

salesorders.sonumber (pk) < customer.sonumber (fk)

I am using Navicat with MariaDB (same as MySQL) and the error I get is:

1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('customer_orders','#sql7a8_3'; CONSTRAINT 'sonumber' FOREIGN KEY ('sonumber') REFERENCES 'salesorder' ('sonumber') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Customer_orders is the database name. I am naming the foreign key 'sonumber' which is the same as the column name in the child table (customer) and the parent table (salesorders). Is that incorrect? Should I give the foreign key another name?

gitpicker

Comment: I don't know as a fact (since I am not familiar with mySQL or Navicat), but I suspect that the name of the constraint cannot have the same name as a field on the table. Try putting an "fk_" in front of the foreign key constrain name. i.e. CONSTRAINT 'fk_sonumber' FOREIGN KEY. Or a typical style is to name a foreign key fk_CHILDTable_PARENTTable. i.e. fk_SALESORDERS_CUSTOMER

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key should have its own unique name, yes. `sonumber_fk` or something similar is a simple naming schema.

You also need to make sure that every entry in the Foreign Key column has a corresponding entry in the Referenced table, otherwise you will not be able to create the foreign key.